# Handling multiple tabs on Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I was trying to build a program using Selenium that would open a browser session for limited time and would not let the user open a few blacklisted sites. My program can detect if the user has opened a blacklisted site on the main tab. **But I am not able to detect whether the user has opened a blacklisted site on some other tab.**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time


time_limit = raw_input('Enter time limit : ') 
x = int(raw_input('Enter number of blacklisted sites : '))

black_listed = list() #Stores blacklisted sites

for i in range(0,x):
    site = raw_input('> ')
    black_listed.append(site)

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

now = time.time()
future = now + int(time_limit)*60

while time.time() < future:
    check = driver.current_url
    for url in black_listed:
        if url in check: #Checks whether current site is blacklisted
            driver.quit()
            exit()

    pass

driver.quit()
```

Comment: What if user just uses Firefox or another browser? There are easier ways to stop people visiting sites, or tracking them for that..

Comment: you can use driver.switchTo().window(tabs.get(1)); tabs = driver.getWindowHandles(); But I do not understand why during a testing session one would open up other sites. Still there are other tools to get the job done easier and cleaner.